# Display a div at the position of mouse click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table of cells, and I want to be able to create a menu on the point of right click. I have an example of my fiddle here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/11381/)

Now the `ContextMenu` class is just a div that I created for this example. As you can see there are no borders to form the actual menu. Now how can I make this menu display at the position my mouse is when I click on one of these cells? Right now it displays under the current table div.

Do I need to mount the menu div under `componentWillMount()` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`onContextMenu` method gives the location of mouse click as `e.pageX (left)` and `e.pageY (top)`. Based on this coordinates position the context menu absolutely.

Also, instead of coupling ContextMenu component's behavior with parent's state, display the ContextMenu component always (but hidden). Something like this

```
var ContextMenu = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {contextMenuLocation: ''};
    },
    render: function() {
        var location = this.state.contextMenuLocation;
        var contentMenuStyle = {
            display: location ? 'block' : 'none',
            position: 'absolute', 
            left: location ? location.x : 0,
            top: location ? location.y : 0
        };
        return (
            <div id="results" style={contentMenuStyle}>
                Menu here
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Parent component's render would look like this

```
render: function(){
  return (<div>
    .....
    <ContextMenu ref="contextMenu" />
  </div>);
}
```

Maintain a reference to contextMenu in parent component

```
componentDidMount: function(){
  this.contextMenu = this.refs.contextMenu;
}
```

Display it like this

```
_onContextMenu: function(e) {
    this.contextMenu.setState({
      contextMenuLocation: {'x' : e.pageX, 'y': e.pageY}
    });
    return false;
}
```

Here is the updated demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/kb3gN/11383/**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! One more thing: I tried to add "return false" inside _onPageClick to hide the menu when user left click on the div, but had no luck. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: you're welcome. You can do `this.contextMenu.setState({contextMenuLocation: ''});` in _onPageClick and it should work fine. Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/kb3gN/11384/